# Images in django's email are not displayed

Tags: django, email

I used EmailMultiAlternatives and django template to create email and send. I can receive the email in gmail but the images are not shown.

In the template I set

```
<img src="https://[my image url]">
```

In the email in gmail the img src turns out to be

https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/...#[my image http url]

but the image is not found

I can access the image by the image's http url from browser. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't know how Gmail does it, but I've set my email client to block all remote images by default. Loading remote images automatically is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

If Gmail thinks a sender or message is suspicious, you won’t see images automatically. Instead, you'll be asked if you want to see the image. More info about images in [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en)